# Citrix login performance

Tags: windows, performance, citrix

How do you go about troubleshooting application startup time in a Citrix environment? We have some users that get very fast startup time, others take forever when starting the same application on similar hardware/network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the profiles. If they are on the same hardware and it's consistently the same users who are slow, look at the profile size. That's the first place we start. Larger profiles take longer to load. So if there's a substantial difference, there you go.

Comment: Some people have this habit of saving their files to the desktop, which is part of the profile. So, the other part of this solution is to encourage everyone to save things to their home directory. Firefox's default of saving downloaded files to the desktop is a Very Bad Thing.

Comment: Another option is to redirect their folders (desktop, My Documents) to the server using Group Policies.  This eliminates the issue and also keeps the files out of the easy to corrupt Profile folders.

Answer (score 2):

Try to establish the point in the logon process there is a delay. I would search the Brian Madden website for an article called Troubleshooting Slow Citrix and Terminal Server Logons. I would link to the site but am not allowed as a new user...

**Note:** If profile bloat is the problem, then you will see a delay whilst 'Loading personal settings' is displayed on screen.

Answer (score 0):

Also check for differences in login scripts between your users.  Users who are mapping lots of drives and having multiple group policies being applied to them will take a lot longer to log in.

Answer (score 0):

Check the number of files that are in the users profile, as having 100's of files will slow the copying of the profile.